# How to filter for MULTIPLE ROWS using Excel search

Tags: excel

So I have an excel spreadsheet containing 100k rows, and I have a list of "unique identifiers" that are listed on some of these rows.

As opposed to clicking the dropdown -> paste unique identifier, rinse and repeat, to grab all of the unique identifiers that I'm looking for, is there a way to say "show me all of the rows that contain this list of 20 unique identifiers"?

Answer (score 0):

I will try and answer the actual question. :/ Just to reiterate: You want to see just the rows with the  "unique identifiers" in another table. Actually will require more information from you.

Are the  "unique identifiers" all in one column?

That is the easiest to solve (if all in one column). I would actually use a separate column to 'mark' these rows. Make a list of the unique identifiers using Formulas(tab) and Define Name. Then write a countif statement in the new column using the new name.  Filter out all 0 values and you are left with all rows that match the other list. I have frequently used this when I need to identify a sub-list in a larger list.

Ex: =COUNTIF(List,A1)

First reply - ignore separate issue
No, there is not quick fix to show the unique fields. I wish there was. The best way that I have found is to do a quick pivot table off to the side and use that field as the main group. You do not even need to complete the pivot table because it will show just a list of unique items, which you can copy and past off if needed. It is a dirty fix but it is much quicker than trying check them through the drop down.

Comment: Is the pivot table going to show the entire row? How would I be able to select multiple unique identifiers that I'm looking for using this method? Thanks for the response too btw! Looking forward to trying this.